# "rostopic echo" of the kinect

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 11.10.

I place the kinect toward white wall

and

rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image

I can see the depth image

But rostopic echo /camera/detph/image

put different numbers(datas).

How can I get the same datas?

And how can I find actual distance using openni driver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41334/%22rostopic-echo%22-of-the-kinect/) by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean different? Are they very different, then something is wrong. If they are just a bit different, then that's normal. It's a sensor that has noise.

For the distances, you would subscribe to a pointcloud2 topic and not the depth image.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0